# How to do the MultiLabelBinarizer in a huge list of lists

Tags: python, scikit-learn, large-files

I am trying to train OneVsRest algorithm where it gets a tf-idf matrix(called x_train) which is of this shape:

> <3323504x900282 sparse matrix of type ''   with
>   119378243 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

and the y_train, which is a list of lists(of length 3323499).
Each member has 5 labels(at max).
So, y_train looks like this:

> [['mysql', 'triggers'], ['mercurial', 'rebase'], ['c#', '.net'], ...]

When I execute this code:

```
ovr_clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(gamma="auto", random_state=42))
ovr_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I get the following message:

> ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data
>   representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a
>   binary array or sparse matrix instead - the MultiLabelBinarizer
>   transformer can convert to this format.

After trying to do the MultiLabelBinarizer, like this:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit_transform(y_train)
```

I get the message:

> MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
>   ----> 2 mlb.fit_transform(y_train)
>
> D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in
>   fit_transform(self, y)
>       884 
>       885         if not self.sparse_output:
>   --> 886             yt = yt.toarray()
>       887 
>       888         return yt
>
> D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py in
>   toarray(self, order, out)
>       960         if out is None and order is None:
>       961             order = self._swap('cf')[0]
>   --> 962         out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
>       963         if not (out.flags.c_contiguous or out.flags.f_contiguous):
>       964             raise ValueError('Output array must be C or F contiguous')
>
> D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in
>   _process_toarray_args(self, order, out)    1185             return out    1186         else:
>   -> 1187             return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)    1188     1189
>
> MemoryError:

I am assuming this happens because it runs out of memory.
Is there a way to do this partially, so I won't run out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

Use the sparse format

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)
mlb.fit_transform(y_train)
```

By the way, you should call "fit" on your entire dataset first and then do a transform on train and test individually. That way if you have labels in y_test that are not in y_train, you won't get an error.